# Save features to KML in particular order in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I have a layer with an attribute called 'label' which has numbers as text ('1', '2', etc...) I want a KML saved and have the features saved by order of int('label'). Is it possible?

Looks like from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138769/is-it-possible-to-sort-the-features-by-an-attribute-programmatically) question it is possible to sort features, but I want to save a KML and have the features saved in a particular order. right now my code for saving the KML layer looks like this:

```
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.includeZ = True
    options.fileEncoding = "utf-8"
    options.driverName = "KML"
    options.overrideGeometryType = QgsWkbTypes.LineStringZ
    options.datasourceOptions = ['NameField=label']
    result = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
                                            layer=clone_layer,
                                            fileName=str(outputlayer),
                                            transformContext=QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
                                            options=options)
```

right now in google earth the namefield will be out of order like this:
[image]

and I need it to be in order.

Comment: Is it possible that you share your KML with us ?

Comment: Unfortunately not since it has some geographic data that I'm not at liberty to share, but the goal is that I can open the file in google earth and the numbers will be in order. I will update the question with a screenshot from google earth with what they look like now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making a new layer in memory and adding the sorted features to it and then saving it as a KML:

```
    def line_sort(item):
        return int(item['label'])
    lines = sorted(self.final_lines.getFeatures(), key=line_sort)
    clone_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=epsg:4326", "lines", "memory")
    clone_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([field for field in self.final_lines.fields()])
    clone_layer.updateFields()
    clone_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(lines)
```