# Sorting table by multiple columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In 2012 the answer was NO!
[Sorting by multiple fields at same time in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41329/how-to-sort-by-multiple-fields-at-the-same-time)

My data is in a SHP file, I want to sort by 3 fields.

Has this changed in the last 4 years?

A solution like in ArcMap would be ideal -so it can be redone as required without hardcoding

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/sorting-records-in-a-table-by-multiple-fields.htm